# how to pass parameter in the var that is using URLFOR

Tags: visualforce, urlfor

```
var iframe_url = '{!URLFOR("/apex/MemberVerification?memberReferral={!Contact.Active_Member_ReferralId__c}")}';
```

Above is piece of code, but not working as expected. I have a button in the detail page. How can I send parameter from detail to Visualforce Page?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to be more specific than *"not working as expected"*. This site is not meant to be a guessing game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is not clear on what you are exactly looking for. At first glance, looks like you have problem with syntax.

You can use following syntax to concatenate parameters inside merge field:

```
var iframe_url = '{!URLFOR("/apex/MemberVerification?memberReferral=" + 
    URLENCODE(Contact.Active_Member_ReferralId__c))}';
```

Note: [URLENCODE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm) is helpful and important when you have characters not allowed in the URL.